# Как применить apply к двум столбцам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Посчитать абсолютное значение отклонения `b` от `c` с использованием `apply` и сохранить результат в столбец `d`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a':[7083.3317, 1249.9998, 3749.9999, 2083.3332], 
                    'b': [182.93, 34.534, 59.334, 84.93],
                    'c': [157.93, 10.534, 24.334, 55.93]})


        a          b        c
0   7083.3317   182.930  157.930
1   1249.9998   34.534   10.534
2   3749.9999   59.334   24.334
3   2083.3332   84.930   55.930
```

К сожалению, нижеприведённое решение не принимается:

```
df['d'] = abs(df['b'] - df['c'])
```

Надо:

```
f = lambda row: abs(row['x'] - row['y'])
df['d'] = df.loc[:, 'b', 'c'].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно без `.apply()` - у Pandas Series есть метод [Series.abs()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
In [25]: df['d'] = (df['b'] - df['c']).abs()

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
           a        b        c     d
0  7083.3317  182.930  157.930  25.0
1  1249.9998   34.534   10.534  24.0
2  3749.9999   59.334   24.334  35.0
3  2083.3332   84.930   55.930  29.0
```

---

Как это сделать при помощи lambda функции:

```
In [28]: df.apply(lambda row: row["b"] - row["c"], axis=1)
Out[28]:
0    25.0
1    24.0
2    35.0
3    29.0
dtype: float64
```

**NOTE:** метод `DataFrame.apply(..., axis=1)` - очень медленный и его стоит использовать только если невозможно найти другое векторизированное решение.

Comment: А с apply  где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 4):

А вот так с apply

```
# использовать настоящие имена колонок
f = lambda row: abs(row['b'] - row['c'])
# набор колонок списком
df['d'] = df.loc[:, ['b', 'c']].apply(f, axis=1)
df
           a        b        c     d
0  7083.3317  182.930  157.930  25.0
1  1249.9998   34.534   10.534  24.0
2  3749.9999   59.334   24.334  35.0
3  2083.3332   84.930   55.930  29.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Что касается ошибки, чтобы выбрать несколько столбцов в `.loc` нужно указать их в виде списка:

```
df.loc[:, ['b', 'c']]
```